# How to open hxxp or other obscured links automatically in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, links

How to open hxxp or other obscured links automatically with Firefox (without copy and paste manually)? For non obscured links I use [Linky Firefox add-on](http://gemal.dk/mozilla/linky.html) <sup>(obsolete, see [archived addons.mozilla.org listing](https://web.archive.org/web/20121221045613/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linky/))</sup>.

From [Wikipedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20121104001852/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hxxp) <sup>(deleted, archived)</sup>:

> hxxp://, sometimes h**p:// or _ttp://, is used in URLs (web links) to
> obscure the fact that one is linking to a http:// website. It is
> generally used to avoid automatic recognition by computer programs.
> For a user to follow this link, it is usually necessary to manually
> copy-paste the link onto the web browser's address bar and replace the
> 'x'es with 't's.

I use [RefControl](https://web.archive.org/web/20171212000508/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) <sup>(obsolete, archived)</sup>, so security is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**QuietUrl**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quieturl/) seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

[image: 1]

Comment: the link now 404 - Oops! We can’t find that page. Others also searching for an alternative https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/trying-to-find-a-replacement-for-quieturl/36644

Comment: I have updated [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1721291/300293) to provide instructions on how to do this, but I must again remind you that `hxxp` is used by security researchers to prevent linking to malicious sites. There should be *zero* valid use cases for converting these to links.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do not visit these sites!

The whole point of hxxp-obfuscated URLs is that it is not safe to visit them. There is *no* assured protection against them, especially not something like [RefControl](https://web.archive.org/web/20171212000508/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/), which simply removed referrers.

Your standard hxxp-obfuscated URL points to malware or phishing, often with [0-day attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)) that antivirus and other remedies will not defend against.

The only reason to visit these sites is if you are a security researcher who knows what they are doing (this means you're using a disposable sandbox or a custom crawler that won't render payloads). There is therefore no reason to deobfuscate them.

(Note: the Wikipedia page you referred to was [removed in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Hxxp) because it was wrong. hxxp is used solely in a security context and while it is a common practice in information security, it is not standardized.)

---

If you actually have some context in which these are used without security concerns (noting again that removing tracking links may help with privacy but will *not* help with security), you could use code like this:

```javascript
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\bhxxp/g, "http");
```

Either paste that into the developer console (from the website, press F12 or click Firefox's <kbd>☰</kbd> Application menu and go to More Tools → Developer Console) or save that in a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) keying on the specific site(s) it is relevant for. This requires an add-on like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

Comment: @Josefine – I'm in the information security industry. We regularly throw hxxp links around between ourselves when discussing phishing attacks and malware sites. See for yourself with a [search for hxxp](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hxxp) ([on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hxxp), if you prefer).